# why field value doesn't show?

Tags: odoo

my problem is that when I use inheritance, records from parent class don't display

this is my class :

```html
class LabTestCashRegister (models.Model):
    _name = "medical.cash"
    _inherit = "medical.lab.patient"
    comment = fields.Text(store=True,size=2000000)
    type_In = fields.Char(default='Reste', readonly=False)
```

and this is my view:

```html
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="medical_lab_cash_tree_id">
    <field name="name">cash</field>
    <field name="model">medical.cash</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree>
        <field name="patient_id"/>
        <field name="cat"/>
        <field name="test_type_id"/>
        <field name="state_money"/>
        <field name="Avance"/>
         <field name="Amount"/>
        <field name="Reste"/>        
        <field name="comment"/>
        <field name="type_In"/>
      </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

(`Amount`, `Reste`, `Avance`,`state_money` exist on the parent class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `LabTestCashRegister` to

```
class LabTestCashRegister (models.Model):
    _inherit = "medical.lab.patient"
    comment = fields.Text(store=True,size=2000000)
    type_In = fields.Char(default='Reste', readonly=False)
```

This should work for you. Let me know if not.

Comment: but I wanna inherit from `medical.lab.patient`

Comment: plz change the _inherit = "medical.lab.patient" to accept ur answer

Comment: yes it does, but why can I use a name as it's a new model??